# Adding scope to constantized string in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to send a scope to an action that creates an instant variable. Here is my attempt:

```
foo_controller.rb

    define_method(:generate_index) do |string, scope|
        instance_variable_set( "@#{string}", (string.camelize.constantize).public_send scope )
    end

   def index
      generate_index("foo", "all")
   end
```

In the above instance, would expect the following to be created:

```
def index
    @foo = Foo.all
end
```

Instead, I am presented with an error stating:

```
unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting ')'
```

Could anybody perhaps assist in pointing out where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Try `instance_variable_set( "@#{string}", string.camelize.constantize.public_send(scope) )` instead ; Also, why not use a `before_filter` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add some brackets.

```
define_method(:generate_index) do |string, scope|
    instance_variable_set( "@#{string}", string.camelize.constantize.public_send(scope))
end
```

Comment: The brackets around `(string.camelize.constantize)` are irrelevant.

Comment: They were already present. The brackets around `scope` are not.

Comment: I know they were, but because you made some changes to the original line, you can strip them out.

Comment: Thank you for helping with exactly what I needed. To extend this, how would I be able to pass multiple scopes into the above code? I tried passing an array with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure, that's probably worth a question in itself.